# Way to partially match a Ruby string using Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm working on 2 cases:

assume I have those var:

```
a = "hello"
b = "hello-SP"
c = "not_hello"
```

1. Any partial matches
   I want to accept any string that has the variable `a` inside, so `b` and `c` would match.
2. Patterned match
   I want to match a string that has `a` inside, followed by `'-'`, so `b` would match, `c` does not.

I am having problem, because I always used the syntax `/expression/` to define Regexp, so how dynamically define an RegExp on Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same syntax to use variables in a regex, so:

```
  reg1 = /#{a}/
```

would match on anything that contains the value of the `a` variable (at the time the expression is created!) and

```
  reg2 = /#{a}-/
```

would do the same, plus a hyphen, so `hello-` in your example.

**Edit:** As Wayne Conrad points out, if `a` contains "any characters that would have special meaning in a regular expression," you need to escape them. Example:

```
a = ".com"
b = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(a))
"blah.com" =~ b
```

Comment: Another option would be to use Regexp.new, i.e. `reg2 = Regexp.new("#{a}-")`.

Comment: @Greg Campbell, yes, but that's more letters :)

Comment: If `a` might have any regexp metacharacters (period, star, etc.), then wrap it in a call to `Regexp.escape`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to comment but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for.The above mentioned answers didn't help me.Hope it help someone new to ruby who just wants a quick fix.

**Ruby Code:**

```
st = "BJ's Restaurant & Brewery"
    #take the string you want to match into a variable
    m = (/BJ\'s/i).match(string)  #(/"your regular expression"/.match(string))
    # m has the match #<MatchData "BJ's">
    m.to_s
    # this will display the match  
 => "BJ's"
```